# Option does not accept multiple answers?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have been trying to import rasters and shapefiles into GRASS GIS 7.2.1 and get the responses:

ERROR: Option  does not accept multiple answers
ERROR: Option  does not accept multiple answers

I have taken out spaces and underscores from the filenames and put them in c:\data and still get this message. I note that when you use GRASS in QGIS 2.18 the filenames are put into quotes, but if you do that in GRASS GIS it doesn't recognize the files anymore.

I am using v.in.ogr for the shapefile and r.in.gdal for the raster. What is the problem?

The screenshots are below. If I do not enter "Name for output raster map" there is only an Import error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: We can't help you (or it is MUCH harder) if you don't show us what you're doing - command from CLI or screen shot if using GUI.

Comment: "GRASS GIS 7.2.1" --> do you see a chance to update to the latest stable version which is 7.4.0?

Comment: Actually I found another way to import rasters. Instead of selecting "Common formats import [r.in.gdal]", I chose "Import of common formats with reprojection [r.import]". That does work. I think there was some problem with the projection when I tried to use the first function.